# Iterate function across dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lda, topic-modeling

I have a dataset containing pre-processed online reviews, each row contains words from online review. I am doing a Latent Dirichlet Allocation process to extract topics from the entire dataframe. Now, I want to assign topics to each row of data based on an LDA function called [get_document_topics](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html).

I found a code from a source but it only prints the probability of a document being assign to each topic. I'm trying to iterate the code to all documents and returns to the same dataset. Here's the code I found...

```
text = ["user"]
bow = dictionary.doc2bow(text)
print "get_document_topics", model.get_document_topics(bow)
### get_document_topics [(0, 0.74568415806946331), (1, 0.25431584193053675)]
```

Here's what I'm trying to get...

```
                  stemming   probabOnTopic1 probOnTopic2 probaOnTopic3  topic 
0      [bank, water, bank]              0.7          0.3           0.0      0 
1  [baseball, rain, track]              0.1          0.8           0.1      1
2     [coin, money, money]              0.9          0.0           0.1      0 
3      [vote, elect, bank]              0.2          0.0           0.8      2
```

Here's the codes that I'm working on...

```
def bow (text):
    return [dictionary.doc2bow(text) in document]

df["probability"] = optimal_model.get_document_topics(bow)
df[['probOnTopic1', 'probOnTopic2', 'probOnTopic3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['probability'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slightly different approach @Christabel, that include your other request with 0.7 threshold:

```
import pandas as pd

results = []

# Iterate over each review
for review in df['review']:
  bow = dictionary.doc2bow(review)
  topics = model.get_document_topics(bow)

  #to a dictionary
  topic_dict = {topic[0]: topic[1] for topic in topics}
  #get the prob
  max_topic = max(topic_dict, key=topic_dict.get)

  if topic_dict[max_topic] > 0.7:
    topic = max_topic
  else:
    topic = 0

  topic_dict['topic'] = topic
  results.append(topic_dict)

#to a DF
df_topics = pd.DataFrame(results)
df = df.merge(df_topics, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Is it helpful and working for you ?
You can then place this code inside of a function and use the '0.70' value as an external parameter so to make it usable in different use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option can be creating a new column in your DF and then iterate over each row in your DF. You can use the *get_document_topics* function to get the topic distribution for each row and then assign the most likely topic to that row.

```
df['topic'] = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    text = row['review_text']
    bow = dictionary.doc2bow(text)
    topic_distribution = model.get_document_topics(bow)
    most_likely_topic = max(topic_distribution, key=lambda x: x[1])
    df.at[index, 'topic'] = most_likely_topic
```

is it helpful ?

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm trying to add a parameter as that I will assign a topic when the topic distribution is greater than 0.7. If the max distribution is lower then that than it will be assigned as topic 0. Do you know how to solve this?